# Disk space fill up with kernel and firewall logs

Tags: release-freya, elementary-website, disk-management

What's wrong with the file system in elementary os Freya? Hi dudes, help me with this issue please. My disk fill up quickly after not much minutes in work with logs system, specifically with kern.log and ufw.log, coming to occupy up to 50 GB of space. Please, help me.

pd. Sorry for my english, I'm Peruvian :)

[image: my filesystem]

Comment: What happens if i disable UFW logging? Can this lower the security of the system? sudo ufw logging off

Comment: I have a SSD and not much space for temporary files with more then 2GB.
My elementary OS partition is only 18GB and i have a lot software installed. How to prevent temporary files from growing above 2GB or less? And what is "Rotated logs" logging, only the Firewall? [![BleachBit - System Rotated logs 12GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGVmw.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGVmw.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely caused by a firewall misconfiguration (which is what `ufw` is), which can be modified to run in low-logging mode with this simple command:

```
sudo ufw logging low
```

Then you will probably want to clear up some space.

#### 1. Rotate your Logs

```
sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

#### 2. Remove old Logs

```
sudo rm -Rf /var/log/*.1 /var/log/*.gz
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It's works perfectly!!! One more time, thanks!!!